# Placeholder for character vector in purrr:map?

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to iterate over a character vector "outcomes"

```
results <- map(outcomes, run("Female", ., predictors))
```

"run" is a user-defined function and "Female" and predictors are additional arguments I pass to the function. Period does not seem to work as a placeholder for each element of outcomes :

```
 Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object '.' not found
```

I would really like to use map instead of a loop.

Comment: `run` will ultimately be a confusing name for your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not identify `.` as a valid parameter for your `run` function. Here, is a sample code which works well:

```
run<-function(outcome,gender,key,predictor){
  paste0(outcome," ",gender," ",key," ",predictor)

}
```

and then call it by map:

```
outcome=c(8:11)

library(purrr)
map(outcome,run,gender="Female",key=1,predictor=5  )
```

if your run function has multiple argument, all of the parameters of run, are the parameters of map now. But, in your code, you did not follow it.

For complete explanation, please find [this link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map).

Comment: Ah... I see. Thank you so much it worked! I am curious about the syntax of map though- do you have a link to documentation that can explain how to pass the arguments properly?

Comment: Or `map(outcomes, ~run("Female", ., predictors))`

Comment: ^Could you explain why I need to add a ~ in front of run to make it work? Run is already a function is it not?